# Appending a dict to Dataframe from CSV is removing the values

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, append

I'm trying to append some values to a CSV file using pandas. The problem is that when I read the CSV and append, the rows that previously was in the CSV are changed to NaN.

I read the file and printed every step to understand what happened, but I coudn't.

```
import pandas as pd
try:
    erro = pd.read_csv('C:\\TESTEPANDAS\\errot.csv', index_col=0,header=0)
except:
    erro = pd.DataFrame({'id':[],'cnj':[],'erro':[]})
print(erro)
erro.to_csv('C:\\TESTEPANDAS\\errot.csv',sep=';',index=False)

for i in range(5):
    erro = erro.append({'id':'id{}'.format(i),'cnj':'cnj{}'.format(i),'erro':'errotxt{}'.format(i)},ignore_index=True)

print(erro)
erro.to_csv('C:\\TESTEPANDAS\\errot.csv',sep=';',index=False)
```

When I try once, this is the result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, cnj, erro]
Index: []
    id   cnj      erro
0  id0  cnj0  errotxt0
1  id1  cnj1  errotxt1
2  id2  cnj2  errotxt2
3  id3  cnj3  errotxt3
4  id4  cnj4  errotxt4
```

If I try again:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [id0;cnj0;errotxt0, id1;cnj1;errotxt1, id2;cnj2;errotxt2, id3;cnj3;errotxt3, id4;cnj4;errotxt4]
    cnj      erro   id
0   NaN       NaN  NaN
1   NaN       NaN  NaN
2   NaN       NaN  NaN
3   NaN       NaN  NaN
4   NaN       NaN  NaN
5  cnj0  errotxt0  id0
6  cnj1  errotxt1  id1
7  cnj2  errotxt2  id2
8  cnj3  errotxt3  id3
9  cnj4  errotxt4  id4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters for writing and reading the csv don't match. Look at the index of the second output - reading back the csv failed, as the separator wasn't given:

```
Index: [id0;cnj0;errotxt0, id1;cnj1;errotxt1...
```

The reading command should be:

```
erro = pd.read_csv('C:\\TESTEPANDAS\\errot.csv', sep=";")
```

Then you get back the same object that you saved in the previous iteration.